# How to make the sub-menu beside its parent item?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have a menu, in this menu some items contains subset items.
When create a subset to an item, the subset items wouldn't be beside the parent item.

**For example:**
In the below code, the item 2 has a subset, but this subset beside item 3 not as expected beside item 2.

**I want**
When I create a subset to any parent item, the subset must be beside the item that belong to it.

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="#"> Item 1 </a> 
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#"> Item 2 </a> 
            <ul>
                <li> <a href="#"> Subset Item 2</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#"> Subset Item 2</a> </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#"> Item 3 </a> 
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#"> Item 4 </a> 
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#"> Item 5 </a> 
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box {
    width:130px;
}
.box ul {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    position:relative;
}
.box ul li {
    margin-bottom:1px;
}
.box ul li a {
    display:block;
    padding:5px;
    background-color:#ff0099;
    color:#fff;
    font:bold 20px arial;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.box ul li a:hover {
    background-color:#b2086e;
    color:#fff;
}
.box ul li ul {
    position:absolute;
    left:131px;
}
.box ul li ul li a {
    width: 135px;
}
```

You can also see the [online JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lionking0/pdcAF/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the `<li>` relatively positioned, rather than the `<ul>`. Then you can set the submenu to be `top: 0` and also `left: 100%` rather than setting a pixel value.

```
.box ul li {
  margin-bottom:1px;
  position: relative;
}

.box ul li ul {
  position:absolute;
  left:100%;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: 1px; /* Styling */
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/pdcAF/1/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot, but **I have an inquiry**. Why we make the `left equal 100%`, and also `top equal 0`. these things I don't understand. **also I have another inquiry**, how do I make the width of sub-menu according to its contents

Comment: Well if you make the `left: 100%` then it'll always be 100% from the left side of it's parent.  That's better than defining a pixel position.  You can actually leave this value out though and it'll still work.  As for your second question, you can't do that because it's absolutely positioned which affects the width (it'll only be as wide as it's parent).  You'll need to set a width I'm afraid. http://jsfiddle.net/pdcAF/3/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/gcnmn/

```
.box ul li ul {
    position:absolute;
    top: 36px;       /* added this line */
    left:131px;
}
```

Comment: This solution maybe not good, because when we make another subset to another parent item, the both subset will be added it in the same position. see the updated [**online JSFiddle code**](http://jsfiddle.net/lionking0/gcnmn/1/). the sub-menu 2 and sub-menu 4 in the same position.